# What is the formula for calculated field to calculate the milliseconds of the field "Created" in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, calculated-column

In SharePoint 2007 List, there is a field (or column) called "Created". It contain the date in which a item is created.

I want to create any field, a calculated field, to help me calculate the milliseconds of the date in the "Created" field.

Any Ideas?

**Additional Information**

For example: 10/10/2010 10:11:12:80 will return the value 80 as the millisecond. If I `=MINUTE[Created]`, it will return the value 11 as the minute. (In this case, I am looking for the millisecond.)

Comment: I would love to know what you're doing with SP that you need to know the created time down to milliseconds - care to share?

Comment: @Ryan, The reason for the need to know the milliseconds is because if there are many new item insert into a list at the same time, I need to create a special & unique serial number based on the time it is created. If at 10:11:12 there are 5 new items, I can't have the 5 of them to have serial number that contain 101112. Therefore, there is a need to know up to the milliseconds. Do let me know how would you retrieve the `milliseconds[Created]`.

Comment: Gotcha - you could use the ID column or an event receiver to create your own unique ID though. Also - if you are expecting that sort of volume of data entry then you may be stretching SharePoints capabilities a bit, probably best to check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude this question: There is no way to retrieve the millisecond from SharePoint 2007 as discussed with Christophe.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint expresses dates in days.

Multiply by 24 to express it in hours, then by 3600 to express it in seconds, then by 1000 to express it in milliseconds:

[Created]*24*3600*1000

If you only want to eep the milliseconds, try this:

([Created]*24*3600-INT([Created]*24*3600))*1000

Comment: Hi Christophe, what I mean is if there is a `=MILLISECOND[Created]`? I don't want to convert the whole things into milliseconds. For example, if I want to know the minutes in the date, I will `=SECOND[Created]`. If I want to know the hour, I will `=HOUR[Created]`. So, there should be a `=MILLISECOND[Created]` right?

Comment: There is no MILLISECOND, but my second formula should do the job.

Comment: Hi Christophe, from my understanding, the [Created] only contain MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM. If that is the case, there is surely no way to eep the milliseconds since there is no milliseconds inside the [Created]. Your method is basically converting the time to milliseconds using the [Created] field. Do correct me if I have mis-understand that [Created] does not contain milliseconds.

Comment: Did you try the formula? [Created] (and dates in general) not stored as date and time in SharePoint, they are stored as a number.

Comment: Thanks Christophe for mentioning that SharePoint store the date and time as a number. Originally, I thought that SharePoint only store MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM only. However the 2nd formula keep returning 0.0 (if the calculated field is 'Number' type) or 0 (if the calculated field is 'String' type). Any insight?

Comment: I did a couple tests, and it seems that you cannot go under the second. I used more precise formulas, but they always return 0.01 or 999.98 ms, which is certainly a rounding issue.

Comment: Hi Christophe, so may I conclude that there is no way to retrieve the millisecond from SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Well, this is my conclusion. Time is stored as a decimal number, but apparently not with enough precision to give you milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the info. By the way, does SharePoint 2010 have enough precision to give milliseconds ?