# CAML Query to Sort list items based on Modified date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem

while sorting sharepoint list items based on 'modified' column, its not considering seconds and milliseconds, i need sorting to be done on Milliseconds too, why because i have multiple list items insertions at a time and i need to order them based on modified date.

The CAML query I am using is

`<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding, and borne out by the comments [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22969/what-is-the-formula-for-calculated-field-to-calculate-the-milliseconds-of-the-fi), that SharePoint Date fields don't actually track milliseconds. Sorry.