# show created column should display seconds with created time after a document save in share point

Tags: development, document-library, powershell, sharepoint-server

I created a site collection with Document Center Template and created a document library, i uploaded documents and i want to see created column should display seconds with created time , because i have a requirement to sort documents based on saved in sharepoint in a custom scan solution.

how it is possible to show seconds also  with time.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the list view xslt.

Another option is to add a calculated field and use below formula

```
=TEXT(Created, "dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: Hi how to add list view xslt

Comment: You should edit the view page using SharePoint Designer. FYI the date value stored contains the complete value including seconds. So I don't think you will get affected by this in your custom solution

Comment: thanks, now i created a calculated column and also it is possible to show milli seconds?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22969/what-is-the-formula-for-calculated-field-to-calculate-the-milliseconds-of-the-fi

Comment: there is no option to show milli seconds right ? and what is the forumula for show date and time like  3/31/2015 3:01:44 PM

Comment: Yes as per the link I provided. I haven't tried myself. But you can calculate it using the other formula

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22593/discussion-between-adilahmed-and-amal-hashim).

Comment: what is the forumula for show date and time like 3/31/2015 3:01:44 PM

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM